# Suppressing ASP.NET PageMethods Documentation Comments

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, comments, webmethod

I have an ASP.NET WebForm application that has some `WebMethod's` in C# that is being called through jQuery's `ajax` functions. Everything is working fine, except I notice that when I view source on the page, I'm seeing something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var PageMethods = function() {
        PageMethods.initializeBase(this);
        this._timeout = 0;
        this._userContext = null;
        this._succeeded = null;
        this._failed = null;
    }
    PageMethods.prototype = {
        _get_path:function() {
            var p = this.get_path();
            if (p) return p;
            else return PageMethods._staticInstance.get_path();},
            CreateNewFranchise:function(name,firstName,lastName,address1,address2,streetSuffixId,city,stateId,county,zip,mainPhoneAreaCode,mainPhoneTypeId,mainPhonePrefix,mainPhoneSuffix,storeCode,storeKey,merchantId,corporateShop,franchiseNumber,succeededCallback, failedCallback, userContext) {
            /// <param name="name" type="String">System.String</param>
            /// <param name="firstName" type="String">System.String</param>
            /// <param name="lastName" type="String">System.String</param>
            /// <param name="address1" type="String">System.String</param>
            /// <param name="address2" type="String">System.String</param>
            /// <param name="streetSuffixId" type="String">System.String</param>
            /// <param name="city" type="String">System.String</param>
            /// <param name="stateId" type="String">System.String</param>
            /// <param name="county" type="String">System.String</param>
            /// <param name="zip" type="String">System.String</param>
            /// <param name="mainPhoneAreaCode" type="String">System.String</param>
            /// <param name="mainPhoneTypeId" type="String">System.String</param>
            /// <param name="mainPhonePrefix" type="String">System.String</param>
            /// <param name="mainPhoneSuffix" type="String">System.String</param>
            /// <param name="storeCode" type="String">System.String</param>
            /// <param name="storeKey" type="String">System.String</param>
            /// <param name="merchantId" type="String">System.String</param>
            /// <param name="corporateShop" type="Boolean">System.Boolean</param>
            /// <param name="franchiseNumber" type="String">System.String</param>
            /// <param name="succeededCallback" type="Function" optional="true" mayBeNull="true"></param>
            /// <param name="failedCallback" type="Function" optional="true" mayBeNull="true"></param>
            /// <param name="userContext" optional="true" mayBeNull="true"></param>
            ...
            ...
            ...
```

What I am wondering is if these `///` lines are necessary and if not, is there a way to make ASP.NET suppress them? To me, they look like they are just XML documentation markups, which shouldn't be necessary. Having about 8 `WebMethod's` in my C#, these lines add up and I'd like to filter them out if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines are just comments and made for a developer convenience during debug. Comments are not generated if one of the following settings in `web.config` are set:

- `<deployment retail="false" />`
- `<compilation debug="false" />`

Plus comments are not generated when `ScriptManager.ScriptMode` property is explicitly set to `Release`.

The class which is responsible for PageMethods script generation is [`PageClientProxyGenerator`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web.Extensions/UI/ScriptManager.cs#1792). And conditions above are described in [`ScriptManager`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web.Extensions/UI/ScriptManager.cs#551) source code:

```
public bool IsDebuggingEnabled {
    get {
        // Returns false when:
        // - Deployment mode is set to retail (override all other settings)
        // - ScriptMode is set to Auto or Inherit, and debugging it not enabled in web.config
        // - ScriptMode is set to Release

        if (DeploymentSectionRetail) {
            return false;
        }
        if (ScriptMode == ScriptMode.Auto || ScriptMode == ScriptMode.Inherit) {
            return AppLevelCompilationSection.Debug;
        }
        return (ScriptMode == ScriptMode.Debug);
    }
}
```

Comment: This absolutely fixed it! Thank you and thanks for adding the extra detail on the `PageClientProxyGenerator`.